# Backbone.js: bind data to Collection using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I've just started using Backbone.js. I want to create a Collection and add some data from an external source.

The data is actually currently in CSV, not JSON, but I could re-render it in JSON if that is going to be a lot easier.

So, two questions:

1. Where do I bind external data to the Collection? It complains if I don't specify a `url` property, but I don't really have a URL in mind - I was planning to bind data via Ajax.
2. Should I re-render my data in JSON, rather than CSV, and use the Collection's `url` property to load it?

I just tried loading data directly into the Collection, rather than via the `url` property:

```
var Cat = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var CatCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Cat
});
var ajaxData = { 'breed' : 'persian' } // simple example of external data
var catCollection = new CatCollection(ajaxData);
catCollection.fetch();
```

But this gives an error: `Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified`.

Comment: but you need an url for the ajax call.

Comment: Oh, so if I specify that URL and it is JSON, it should "just work"? What happens if the URL is a CSV file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either initialize/reset your collection with an array created elsewhere without using the fetch method for your collection

```
var ajaxData = [{ 'breed' : 'persian' }]; // Backbone.Collection expects an array
var catCollection = new CatCollection(ajaxData);
// catCollection.fetch(); fetch will try to update the data from the server
```

or use the built-in url/parse to build your models

```
var CatCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Cat,
    url: "your ajax source",
    parse: function (csv) {
        //convert your csv in an array of objects
        return csvtoarray;
    },
    fetch: function (options) {
        options = options || {};
        options.dataType = "text";
        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
    }
});
var catCollection = new CatCollection();
catCollection.fetch();
```

Converting your data server-side to JSON will probably be easier than trying to write a CSV parser in JS.

Comment: The second method -- overriding parse -- is clearly preferable but as far as I can tell doesn't work: The sync method will throw an error upon not receiving JSON so will never call parse. What I think you'll need to do is override Backbone.sync and parse. I'm about to give this a shot anyway.

Comment: @TomP You're right, it was missing a datatype. Overriding fetch should be enough though.